# How to access the magic _destroy attribute used in accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On a form submit that fails because of a validation error, I need to hide form elements that have been marked for destroy.

I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for, which adds a _destroy field to the form. How do I access the value of this field after a form submit?

```
>>  f2.hidden_field :_destroy
=> "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"true\" ...
>>  f2.object[:_destroy]
=> nil
```

Id and other attributes work as expected.

```
>>  f2.object[:id]
=> 10
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check with Object.marked_for_destruction? if it's true then the record marked,

for your code

```
if f2.marked_for_destruction? 
  # your code here
end
```

Comment: That works. Just for my edification, any suggestions on how I could have figured this out for myself?

Comment: rails Activerecord Api documentation can be good resource for depth process  https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation